# Search Arrays in Hive

Tags: arrays, string, set, hive, collect

I need to search an array function for specific values in hive.

I have a table that creates a row for each event.  I used `collect_set(event_id)` to roll the table up to the person level.  I now need to search the array to put users into separate categories.  I tried using a case when statement, `find_in_set`, and `in_file` but none of those functions work on arrays.

Any ideas?  Can I convert an array into a string?  Ideally I would have used a `group_concat` function in SQL - but hive does not support it

Answer (score 4):

`ARRAY_CONTAINS(events, search_param)` will return a Boolean if `search_param` is found in the events array.

It's available in Hive 0.7.1, and possibly earlier versions.